# HTML 5 Form Element Value

Tags: php, html

So this is not really a problem I am having but I was hoping to get some feedback on how I am processing the form data sent to the server.

I am dealing with gigantic form with tons of select boxes, each with a large number of options.

For simplicity sake, let's say this is how the form looks like:

```
<form action="demo_form.php">
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="merc">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On the server, I need to, among other things, generate a PDF report. Obviously, on submission, the code above will send "volvo" instead of "Volvo XC90", which is what I will need to display to end users on reports, and so on.

Currently (as always, but I just realized this is a pain given how large the form is), I have written a function to make the values "pretty" again. Something like this:

```
function returnPretty($uglyArr) {
  $pretty_csv = array(
    "volvo"=>"Volvo XC90",
    "saab"=>"Saab 95",
    "merc"=>"Mercedes SLK",
    "audi"=>"Audi TT",
  );

  $prettyArr = array();
  foreach($uglyArr as $column) {
    if($pretty_csv[$column]) {
        $value = $pretty_csv[$column];
        array_push($prettyArr, $value);
    } else {
        array_push($prettyArr, $column);
    }
  }
  return $prettyArr;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Especially when I am working with NoSQL.

Thanks.

Comment: This is how many people do it. In some of my scripts I use the same associative array to create the menu and process the submission.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about coding style and application design are more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even know that existed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of playing with string value, you should play with numbers. Because Numbers process by processor/memory much faster & efficiently than the string. Just replace volvo to 0 like this.

```
<form action="demo_form.php">
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="0">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="1">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="2">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="3">Audi TT</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This for server side ..

```
 function returnPretty($uglyArr) {
      $pretty_csv = array(
        0 =>"Volvo XC90",
        1 =>"Saab 95",
        2 =>"Mercedes SLK",
        3 =>"Audi TT",
      );

      $prettyArr = array();
      foreach($uglyArr as $column) {
        if($pretty_csv[$column]) {
            $value = $pretty_csv[$column];
            array_push($prettyArr, $value);
        } else {
            array_push($prettyArr, $column);
        }
      }
      return $prettyArr;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I do that where possible, because I find it painful to do updates otherwise.

Comment: Yes. A lot work to do .. but once it done .. it will optimize with 60 to 70%

Comment: Sold! Something for the next iteration.